# Using Pundit Policy Scopes with Searchkick Results

Tags: ruby, security, ruby-on-rails

We are using Searchkick to run our elasticsearch and Pundit to authorize users for specific actions. Below is our module `SearchkickScope` that does it's best to scope results to those found via the `policy_scope` supplied by Pundit. Since this is a security related module, I would love some outside opinions on this implementation.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

# This allows searchkick to be easily implemented in a controller action
# while scoping the search to respect the current user's permissions via
# the pundit policy. It does so by grabbing all of the resource ids from the
# policy scope and then adding a where clause to the search query.
module SearchKickScope
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # Creates a search query that respects a policy scope.
  # @example
  # def index
  #   search(Lead)
  # end
  # @param klass [Class] the class to search.
  def search(klass)
    @klass = klass
    @search = klass.search(search_query, **scoped_options)
    render json: @search.results, meta: search_meta, status: :ok
  end

  private

  # Return a query, if the q param is not present, return * for a wildcard
  # search. This is to have consistent indexing and searching behavior more
  # similar to a traditional index action.
  # @return [String] the query.
  def search_query
    params[:q].presence || '*'
  end

  # Return the hash of the search options. These can be present in the
  # opts param. This method is safe to use with strong parameters.
  # @return [Hash] the search options.
  def search_options
    params[:opts] ? params[:opts].to_unsafe_h : {}
  end

  # Merges all other options with the scoped ids, ensuring that the search
  # will only return records that are within the punditp policy scope.
  # @return [Hash] the search options.
  def scoped_options
    opts = search_options
    if opts[:where]&.[](:id).present?
      opts[:where][:id] = scope_ids & opts[:where][:id]
    else
      opts[:where] ||= {}
      opts[:where][:id] = scope_ids
    end
    opts.deep_symbolize_keys
  end

  # Return a meta object for searchkick queries that can be serialized
  # and returned with the search results.
  # @param search [Searchkick::Relation] the search results.
  # @return [Hash] the meta object.
  def search_meta
    {
      total: @search.size,
      page: @search.current_page,
      per_page: @search.per_page,
      total_pages: @search.total_pages,
      aggs: @search.aggs
    }
  end

  # Returns the ids of the records that are in the current user's scope. Memoized.
  # @return [Array<String>] the ids of the records in the current user's scope.
  def scope_ids
    @_pundit_policy_authorized = true # Override the authorization check because this is outside normal usage.
    @scope_ids ||= policy_scope(@klass).pluck(:id)
  end
end
```

**Example Usage**

```rb
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
  include Pundit::Authorization
  include SearchkickScope

  def index
    search(Lead)
  end
end
```